# Blank view for UIViewController pushed with button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to push a UIViewController on to my navigation stack using the following:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
TestViewController *lvc = (TestViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES];
```

TestViewController has a scene in the storyboard and ViewDidLoad is always called BUT if I trigger this code with a button click I get a blank view added the the navigation stack. It has a navigation header and back button. If I click the back button, the calling view is also blank.

If I call this code in the ViewDidLoad of my calling UIViewController it works as expected and I can see the view from the storyboard. The back button then works fine.

Could my original view be getting deallocated?

Thanks very much

Comment: The button itself is programatically created so there's no segues to it. I get the same error if I push the view controller within methods from the UITableViewDelegate such as cellForRowAtIndexPath or didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: If I create a segue to the TestViewController in the storyboard I get the same thing, it pushes and empty view and then when I click back I get another empty view.

Comment: The sequence is as follows: I have a UIViewController with a table view in it. This is embedded within a navigation controller. The table cell pushes another UIViewController with a table view in it. This second table is where the problem is - when I push a viewcontroller here it turns out blank. So the viewcontroller with the second table isn't embedded but I thought I only needed to embed the first one?

Comment: I figured it out, predictably I did something stupid but I guess it could help someone else one day...

I was popping the current view off the navigation stack in viewWillDisappear.